# Unit Testing of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, uitableview

I have unsuccessfully tried to get an instance of a custom `UITableViewCell` in order to unit test it with the `SenTestingKit` framework. This is the code I used in my testing class:

```
CustomTableViewCell *cell =  nil;
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

for (id oneObject in nib) 
    if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CustomTableViewCell class]])
        cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)oneObject;
```

I know it loads the NIB properly because the array `nib` contains an instance of the class `CustomTableViewCell` at its first position but i haven't managed to get it out of the array at all.

Has anyone achieved the testing of `UITableViewCell` ? Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Any help or directions would be immensely appreciated

EDIT:

I have solved the issue using the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method to initialize the `UITableViewCell` class instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running these tests out of container (simulator), anything that relies on `loadView` being called is likely not going to be testable. I recommend unit testing that which can be tested out of container only.

Comment: What do you mean by "container"?

Comment: I am already using application testing, which can only be run on the phone. But i already solved it. Thanks anyway